# accumulator in pyspark with dict as global variable

Tags: dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark, accumulator

Just for learning purpose, I tried to set a dictionary as a global variable in accumulator the add function works well, but I ran the code and put dictionary in the map function, it always return empty.

But similar code for setting list as a global variable

```
class DictParam(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self,  value = ""):
        return dict()

    def addInPlace(self, acc1, acc2):
        acc1.update(acc2)


if  __name__== "__main__":
    sc, sqlContext = init_spark("generate_score_summary", 40)
    rdd = sc.textFile('input')
    #print(rdd.take(5))



    dict1 = sc.accumulator({}, DictParam())


    def file_read(line):
        global dict1
        ls = re.split(',', line)
        dict1+={ls[0]:ls[1]}
        return line


    rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: file_read(x)).cache()
    print(dict1)
```

Comment: my problem is that the map is always empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `print(dict1())` simply gets executed before the `rdd.map()`  does.

In Spark, there are 2 types of [operations](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-releases/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations):

- transformations, that *describe* the future computation
- and actions, that call for action, and actually trigger the execution

Accumulators are updated only when [some action is executed](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-releases/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators):

> Accumulators do not change the lazy evaluation model of Spark. If they
>   are being updated within an operation on an RDD, their value is only
>   updated once that RDD is computed as part of an action.

If you check out the end of this section of the docs, there is an example exactly like yours:

```
accum = sc.accumulator(0)
def g(x):
    accum.add(x)
    return f(x)
data.map(g)
# Here, accum is still 0 because no actions have caused the `map` to be computed.
```

So you would need to add some action, for instance:

```
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: file_read(x)).cache() # transformation
foo = rdd.count() # action
print(dict1)
```

Please make sure to check on the details of various RDD functions and accumulator peculiarities because this might affect the correctness of your result. (For instance, `rdd.take(n)` will by default [only scan one partition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#take(int)), not the entire dataset.)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it now.

Comment: IMO, that's really painful. You may have just transformations but at the end of the day, your code is executing, the lambda called via the map() will trigger. But the accumulator is empty. That's just plain painful and useless.

Having to have an action means a heavy cost. A single `count()` may be a difference of hours of job runtime.

I just don't understand the point of having accumulators if they're going to trick you into thinking they're going to work yet they simply don't without the heavy cost of an action.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who arrives at this thread looking for a Dict accumulator for pyspark: the accepted solution does not solve the posed problem.

The issue is actually in the `DictParam` defined, it does not update the original dictionary. This works:

```
class DictParam(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self,  value = ""):
        return dict()

    def addInPlace(self, value1, value2):
        value1.update(value2)
        return value1
```

The original code was missing the return value.

Answer (score 1):

> For accumulator updates performed inside actions only, their value is
>   only updated once that RDD is computed as part of an action

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did not quite understand, why in my code, the dictionary as global variable did not update, keeps to be empty? I tired list case, it works well. Could you explain more ? thanks in advance