# Unable to run accumulator of type dictionary on rdd in in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

This script creates an accumulator `accumulate_dict`. It appears to work well, for example: `inc("foo")` followed by `inc("foo")` updates the accumulator to `Accumulator<id=1, value={'foo': 2}>`. But when I run the last line which is running it on an rdd, it fails with the error: `File "<stdin>", line 6, in addInPlace
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`. Does PySpark try to hash the accumulator in some way? How can I update this dictionary using accumulator?

```
from pyspark import AccumulatorParam, SparkContext

rdd = sc.parallelize(["foo", "bar", "foo", "foo", "bar"])

class SAP(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, value):
        return value.copy()
    def addInPlace(self, v1, v2):
        v3 = dict(v1)
        v3[v2] = v3.get(v2, 0) + 1
        return v3

accumulate_dict = sc.accumulator({}, SAP())
def inc(x):
    global test
    test += x

rdd.foreach(inc)
```

References: 
[Source code for pyspark.accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/accumulators.html) 
[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44640184/5142270)

Comment: This is not how accumulator works. `AccumulatorParam.addInPlace` [is](https://github.com/zero323/pyspark-stubs/blob/9af2eda12c1982aa52b2bc910a38b08d93396d2b/third_party/3/pyspark/accumulators.pyi#L37) `def addInPlace(self, value1: T, value2: T) -> T: ...` (both arguments and return type have to be the same - it is `reduce` like operation).  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41398242/).

Comment: The solution with Counters that you have linked to is perfect for my requirement. Thank you very much

Comment: I did try that in case of dictionary where both were dictionaries, but I'll try that again and update my question with that snippet as well